# On boundedness of an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Suppose that $g$ is a continuous and bounded function from $\mathbb{R}$ to a Banach space $X$ (which is finite) and $M$ is a square matrix of order $m$.

$e^X$ is the matrix exponential.

If I have an integral of the following form:

$$G(t)=\int_{\sigma}^{t}e^{-M(t-s)}g(s)ds$$

How to prove that the integral $G(t)$ is bounded?

Comment: These question misses a lot of details. What is the dimension of $X$? What are domain and codomain of $g$ and $G$? Is the integrand function an exponential of a matrix? What do you mean by "bounded": convergent for every $t$ or uniformly bounded on $t$? As it is at the moment, the definition of $G$ does not make sense.

Comment: Are there some details missing here? How does the product in the integrand make sense?

Comment: Does $g$ maps into $\mathbb R^m$? Hint: $s\mapsto e^{-M(t-s)}$ is continuous.

Comment: In fact, the dimension of $X$ is finite. $g$ is a continuous and bounded function from $\mathbb{R}$ to a Banach space $X$ (which is finite).

Comment: @Kaydjee where do you get stuck? Integral of a continuous function on a compact interval is well defined...

Comment: I have use the norm of the Banach space $X$ that I have denoted $\Vert . \Vert$. When developping, I get the following result:

Comment: @Kaydjee your sentence stops after ":". The Lebesgue integral of a continuous function $f$ on a **compact** interval mapping into a **finite dimensional** Banach space is the same as the Riemann integral. Notice that $\|\int_a^b f(x) \| \le \int_a^b \|f(x)\| \le |b-a| \|f\|_\infty$.